# Нет доступных конструкторов

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Класс на который ругается.

Room.cpp

```
#include "Room.h"
Room::Room()
{
}

Room::~Room()
{
}
```

Room.h

```
#pragma once
#include "FPoint.h"

class Room {

public:
  Room();
  ~Room();

  FPoint pos;
  FPoint size;
  FPoint center;

};
```

main.cpp

```
#include <gl/freeglut.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include "Room.h"
using namespace std;

void init2D(float r, float g, float b);
void display(void);
void centerOnScreen();
void drawObject();

void generateRooms();
bool appendRoom(Room newRoom);
void drawRooms();
int RandomRange(int min, int max);
bool collisionDetect(Room a, Room b);

int window_x;
int window_y;

int window_width = 800;
int window_height = 600;

char *window_title = "Sample OpenGL FreeGlut App";

const int N = 5;
vector<Room> rooms;

void main(int argc, char **argv) {
  srand((unsigned)time(nullptr));
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  centerOnScreen();
  glutInitWindowSize(window_width, window_height);
  glutInitWindowPosition(window_x, window_y);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE);
  glutCreateWindow(window_title);

  init2D(0,0,0);

  glutDisplayFunc(display);

  glutMainLoop();
}

void generateRooms() {
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    Room newRoom;
    newRoom.size.x = RandomRange(3, 10);
    newRoom.size.y = RandomRange(3, 10);
    newRoom.pos.x = RandomRange(0, window_width - newRoom.size.x);
    newRoom.pos.y = RandomRange(0, window_height - newRoom.size.y);
    if (!appendRoom(newRoom)) {
        i--;
    }
  }
}

bool appendRoom(Room newRoom) {
  if (rooms.empty()) {
    newRoom.pos.x *= 10;
    newRoom.pos.y *= 10;

    newRoom.size.x *= 10;
    newRoom.size.y *= 10;

    newRoom.center.x = newRoom.pos.x + (newRoom.size.x / 2);
    newRoom.center.y = newRoom.pos.y + (newRoom.size.y / 2);

    rooms.push_back(newRoom);
    return true;
  }
  else {

  }
}


void drawRooms() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {

  }
}

void init2D(float r, float g, float b) {
  glClearColor(r, g, b, 0.0);
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  gluOrtho2D(0.0, window_width, 0.0, window_height);
}

void display(void) {
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  drawObject();
  glutSwapBuffers();
}

void drawObject() {
  glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);

  glBegin(GL_POINTS);
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    glVertex2i(10 + 5 * i, 110);
  }
  glEnd();

  glFlush();
}

void centerOnScreen() {
  window_x = (glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_WIDTH) - window_width) / 2;
  window_y = (glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_HEIGHT) - window_height) / 2;
}

int RandomRange(int min, int max) {
  return min + rand() % (max - min + 1);
}

bool collisionDetect(Room a, Room b) {
  if (a.pos.x < b.pos.x + b.size.x &&
        a.pos.x + a.size.x > b.pos.x &&
        a.pos.y < b.pos.y + b.size.y &&
        a.pos.y + a.size.y > b.pos.y) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

**Ошибка**

Ошибка  C2558   class "Room": нет доступных конструкторов копии или конструктор копии объявлен как "explicit"

[Весь проект](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By97iY3-_VpeRzRIVm5raExJYnc)

Так же надо зайти Сервис -> Диспетчер пакетов NuGet -> Управление пакетами NuGet для решения и установить:

1. nupengl.core.redist
2. nupengl.core

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Выложите код программы и сообщение об ошибке в тексте вопроса.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что нужно скрин экрана оформит как текст

Comment: Вы бы всё же в следующий раз пробовали выложить реально минимальный пример, а не дамп всего кода.

Comment: в следующий раз все учту. спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ругается, что нет конструктора копирования. Попробуйте его объявить и определить.

```
Room(const Room& room);
```